# Writing the right tag question

Tags: do-support, tag-questions

I want to write a tag question at the end of this sentence:

> That white house over there used to belong to your family, ..............?

I think the only right choice is "didn't it" but I'm not sure. Is "wasn't it" also correct? Because the main clause is positive and it doesn't have auxiliary verb, I chose that tag question.

Comment: You're certainly correct that it shouldn't be *wasn't it?* However, the sentence could be followed by any number of things, such as *don't you think?*, *right?*, or even *or am I wrong?* Unless this is a multiple choice question (in which case you should provide the finite set of answers), it's too open ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct tag choice for a question where the verb is 'used to' uses the verb 'did'.

> We normally make tags after used to with auxiliary did:
>
> He used to be your boss, did he?
>
> We used to love going to the museum, didn’t we?

[Used to (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past/used-to)

Comment: So it can be positive or negative?

Comment: We can use a positive statement, followed by a positive tag, to express one or more of curiosity, surprise, disbelief, shock, anger, sarcasm or interest.

Comment: If there was a multiple choice question, you would choose "did it" or "didn't it" for that sentence?

Comment: You could choose either. "Did it?", perhaps if you have recently heard that fact, and wish to express e.g. interest or curiosity, and "didn't it?" if you wish to ask for confirmation.

Comment: @MichaelH - Sans additional context, I wouldn't be inclined to use "did it?" as a tag question in the sentence provided in the OP's example; "didn't it?" would be my clear-cut preference.

Comment: I don't see it as clear-cut. I cannot see any compelling reason to choose either did or didn't, especially, as you say, without additional context.

Comment: It might be regional then. One sounds quite natural to me, the other rather odd – unless the speaker was trying to express skepticism from a prior statement, perhaps.

Comment: Without any additional context, as a standalone sentence, *did he?* sounds completely wrong to me. It's not something somebody would come out with out of the blue. *Didn't he?*, however, sounds completely natural to me without any additional context.